# jQuery Mobile How to Refresh Tab Content with a Remote Url?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile tabs widget, when I load remote page content by set the href property with a url, the remote page is a html fragment which also uses some jQuery Mobile widgets, but the remote content loaded, it is plain html, no style and no event.
How do I refresh the remote content ?

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, the tab widget uses the jQueryUI ta widget and has the same API.  You can use the load() event to catch when a remote url has been loaded and then call enhanceWithin() on the panel.

Tab API:  http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load

enhanceWithin: http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/